# Why is the default value of the TCPClient's ReceiveBufferSize is 8192?

Tags: c#, .net, tcp, tcpclient

According to the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.receivebuffersize.aspx) the ReceiveBufferSize defaults to 8192.
I checked and it's not a result of a power of two which makes sense when using buffers.
Is there a special reason? Maybe due to the fact that there is some extra overhead with TCP?

Comment: Have you tried calculating 2^13? You'll be pleasantly surprised!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 to the power of 13 is 8192. So, yes it's a power of 2.

Also note it's also a multiple of 4096 which is incidentally the most popular virtual memory page size.

Comment: Oh, I miscalculated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Traditionally, memory managers and paging files in the operating system work on pages that are sized in powers of 2. This allows very efficient multiply/divide operations to be performed with left/right shift operations. When working with a buffer, the worst case scenario is to have a buffer with size 1 byte longer than the page size (that would result in an extra page swap with very low benefit). So the default buffer sizes will also tend to be implemented in factors of two.